# OAuth 2 provider: storing client credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0

What are the best practices for storing client creds when implementing an OAuth2 provider?

I can store access_token/refresh_token/auth_code as a salted hash (just like passwords) if I decide that every time client requests a new one I issue a new one.  But in the case of the client_secret I need to be able to show it along the client_id on the app registration page, so I can't keep only the hash.

Thanks!
Lev

Answer (score 1):

Using a machine generated client secret is only [one of many means](http://self-issued.info/docs/rfc6749.html#client-authentication) to authenticate a client application. I assume this is what you want to use in your service. In this case you already answered your question, you have to store the secret in plain text as long as you want to be able to communicate it to application developers at any time.

If this is not acceptable for you, consider choosing a different solution, such as letting the developer set the secret like you would do with a password, and never store the plaintext; or use a private/public key pair authentication scheme like [MAC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hammer-oauth-v2-mac-token-02).